# Semantic logging In-Proc and Out-Proc

Tags: azure, logging, azure-sql-database, azure-storage, semantic-logging

I'm using Semantic logging with Windows Azure Websites,

> I wonder Using Semantic logging using Azure website and store log in Azure Table storage and Azure SQL db is Inproc or out Proc ?

Can anyone elaborate more on this please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general we don't recommend storing log file data in Storage Tables. See the section entitled "Are you avoiding append-only and prepend-only patterns?" in the [Storage Performance and Scalability Checklist](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-performance-checklist/#subheading28).